# Spring boot interface declaring static method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm wondering about one pure function, should I declared it as static method or as instance method in Spring boot app. Because I think the best place for this function is the Service class of the entity, in the case of declaring it as static, it should be placed in the interface, but I have some concerns that this is not following the best practices. I added the similar function to mint below.

```
public boolean isDone(String x) {
   return x.equals(EntityState.DONE);
}
```

Comment: Why is there a parameter to the method?  A service class could delegate to the entity to ask if it's done.  So the entity itself will tell you if it's done (encapsulation), to avoid leaking of `EntityState`.

Comment: Why should it be in the service, it should be on the entity. You shouldn't pass state around if the entity (or the class itself) can answer the question. Why would I need to retrieve the entity, prune the data out of the entity, call a service method. While I could be calling the `entity.isDone` in one pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to be checking the state of an entity, my preference would be to add this as an instance method on the entity class.

It really isn't clear if this interface has some other purpose or if it is created just to host this static method, so it isn't clear what the advantage is of having it. Putting the method on the service is ok if there is some reason to avoid adding the method to the entity class.

It would be better to use enums than to compare strings. You can also make this safer by reversing the order like

```
 EntityState.DONE.equals(x);
```

This way if x is null it doesn't throw a NPE.